# double proxy statements for apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy

As you can see I am trying to get both / and /BowlingFacelets/faces/ to point to the same place.

The problem is that the JSF pages will add /BowlingFacelets/faces/ when I sumbit the forms. I however don't want the end user to have to type such a long statement to start the app. Is there a way to do this?

Note that this will work if I manually add

```
score.megahooked.com/BowlingFacelets/faces to the URL
ProxyPass / http://megahooked.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://megahooked.com:8080/
```

This will not work correctly

```
score.megahooked.com/createEvent.xhtml
```

since when submitting the new URL will be
    score.megahooked.com/BowlingFacelets/faces/updateEvent.xhtml which is not found.

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName score.megahooked.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://megahooked.com:8080/BowlingFacelets/faces/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://megahooked.com:8080/BowlingFacelets/faces/
    ProxyPass /BowlingFacelets/faces/ http://megahooked.com:8080/BowlingFacelets/faces/
    ProxyPassReverse /BowlingFacelets/faces/ http://megahooked.com:8080/BowlingFacelets/faces/

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be the using of mod_proxy_html. It can parse HTML documents and rewrite URLs inside. Here for example I make the application "restfrontend" (mapped to "/restfrontend") accessible as root application (mapped to "/")

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On
ProxyHTMLExtended On
ProxyHTMLMeta On
ProxyHTMLLogVerbose On
ProxyHTMLURLMap ^/restfrontend()$ $1 [LR]
ProxyHTMLURLMap /restfrontend/ /

ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /restfrontend /
ProxyHTMLDoctype HTML
```

I would strongly dis-advice to do it. This module is very hard to configure. Configuration of two possible paths in the same time will be a nightmare.

Much better solution is to deploy the application as ROOT directly in the Tomcat and add some redirects for additional URLs shortcuts (RewriteRule with [R=301] option).